# 'plead' vs 'plead for'

Tags: difference

What are the similarities and differences? [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plead) exemplifies but doesn't contrast them:

> 5 [transitive, intransitive] to argue in support of somebody/something
>   [5.1.] **plead something**
>   [Example:] She appeared on television to **plead** the cause of political prisoners everywhere.
>   [5.2.] **plead for somebody/something**
>   [Example:] The United Nations has **pleaded for** a halt to the bombing.

What would happen if 5.1 used **plead for**, and 5.2 **plead**?
Also, why does [plead for a stay](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hs=usR&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&channel=sb&q=%22plead+for+a+stay%22&oq=%22plead+for+a+stay%22&gs_l=serp.3...29417.29865.0.30034.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.cfr...0...1.1.58.serp..4.0.0.6-S_UvknWnU) prevail over [plead a stay](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hs=1D7&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&channel=sb&q=%22plead+a+stay%22&oq=%22plead+a+stay%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.39275.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.cfr...0...1..58.serp..5.1.71.o6sz1AMYXgw)?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation is "plead something" has legal overtones and implies you're arguing or claiming as you might in a trial. "Plead the 5th" is sometimes used jokingly in conversation in the US to mean "I'm not going to say anything more" and is a reference to exercising your constitutional right under the [5th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) to not incriminate yourself. It is related somewhat to legal pleading but it isn't always about a legal situation.

> After my scholarship was unfairly revoked, I went to the provost to plead my case for it to be reinstated.

To "plead for" has less of a legal connotation and is more synonymous with "to beg or to implore".

[Rodney King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney_King) **plead for** an end to the rioting in Los Angeles when he said

> People, I just want to say, can we all get along?

Answer (score 0):

> ...why does plead for a stay prevail over plead a stay?

Plead  =  to present the facts/arguments
Plead for = to ask|petition the court to take some action

When asking the court to issue a stay, counsel *pleads for* a stay.